# iphone sdk: How to implement deletion animation from apple's notes app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uianimation

is there a way to somehow use the same animation apple in the notes app, when notes are deleted? The same animation is used again in the camera app and is triggered when you delete a pic. Can anyone help me out on this?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. Apple hasn't exposed the transition animation that Notes, Photos, and Mail use—it's considered a private API, and an app using it has just about no chance of making it into the App Store. If you'd like access to that transition, I'd suggest [filing a feature request for it](http://bugreport.apple.com).